# What is `self` in Akka?

Tags: scala, actor, akka

Just reading through Akka samples, cant't understand how is `self.reply` defined? As far as I can see, `self reply` is used inside `receive` blocks to reply to a message. But as far as `reply` is a method of `self`, then `self` is what?

PS: BTW, may you recommend a good quickstart article about Akka basics and remote actors with Scala - I'd appreciate if you could post a link as a comment here. Right now I am reading [this](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.1/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`self` is a reference to the ActorRef instance that contains that actor.

When you create a new actor in Akka, the `actorOf[class]` method returns an instance of ActorRef, not of your actual Actor implementation, the actor itself is hidden.  This ActorRef is what you use to interact with the Actor.  So the `self` can be used by the actor itself to get this reference.

For example, if your actor wanted to send a message to itself, it would do

```
self ! Message
```